# Extract word and integer from Html file content using python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

HTML content:

```
   <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-left:0pt;padding-Right:0.75pt;padding-Top:0.75pt;padding-Bottom:0pt;width:38.46%;" valign="top">
    <p style="margin-bottom:0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-left:13.7pt;;text-indent:0pt;;color:#000000;font-size:9pt;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;">Basic earnings (loss) per share</p></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-left:0pt;padding-Right:0.75pt;padding-Top:0.75pt;padding-Bottom:0pt;width:1.08%;" valign="bottom">
    <p style="text-align:right;margin-bottom:0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-left:0pt;;text-indent:0pt;;color:#000000;font-size:9pt;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;"> </p></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-left:0pt;padding-Right:0.75pt;padding-Top:0.75pt;padding-Bottom:0pt;width:1%;white-space:nowrap;" valign="bottom">
    <p style="margin-bottom:0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-left:0pt;;text-indent:0pt;;color:#000000;font-size:9pt;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;"> </p></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-left:0pt;padding-Right:0.75pt;padding-Top:0.75pt;padding-Bottom:0pt;width:9.22%;white-space:nowrap;" valign="bottom">
    <p style="text-align:right;margin-bottom:0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-left:0pt;;text-indent:0pt;;color:#000000;font-size:9pt;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;">0.08</p></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-left:0pt;padding-Right:0.75pt;padding-Top:0.75pt;padding-Bottom:0pt;width:1%;white-space:nowrap;" valign="bottom">
    <p style="margin-bottom:0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-left:0pt;;text-indent:0pt;;color:#000000;font-size:9pt;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;"> </p></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-left:0pt;padding-Right:0.75pt;padding-Top:0.75pt;padding-Bottom:0pt;width:1.08%;" valign="bottom">
    <p style="text-align:right;margin-bottom:0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-left:0pt;;text-indent:0pt;;color:#000000;font-size:9pt;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;"> </p></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-left:0pt;padding-Right:0.75pt;padding-Top:0.75pt;padding-Bottom:0pt;width:1%;white-space:nowrap;" valign="bottom">
    <p style="margin-bottom:0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-left:0pt;;text-indent:0pt;;color:#000000;font-size:9pt;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;"> </p></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-left:0pt;padding-Right:0.75pt;padding-Top:0.75pt;padding-Bottom:0pt;width:9.22%;white-space:nowrap;" valign="bottom">
    <p style="text-align:right;margin-bottom:0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-left:0pt;;text-indent:0pt;;color:#000000;font-size:9pt;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;">0.65</p></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-left:0pt;padding-Right:0.75pt;padding-Top:0.75pt;padding-Bottom:0pt;width:1%;white-space:nowrap;" valign="bottom">
    <p style="margin-bottom:0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-left:0pt;;text-indent:0pt;;color:#000000;font-size:9pt;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;"> </p></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-left:0pt;padding-Right:0.75pt;padding-Top:0.75pt;padding-Bottom:0pt;width:1.08%;" valign="bottom">
```

I want to extract integer which is coming after the line having word `Basic`.
Output should be 0.08

My code: Able to extract line containing word "Basic", but not able to extract "0.08"

```
import re
# Use regular expression to find the line containing "Basic"
pattern = re.compile(r".*Basic.*", re.IGNORECASE)
matches = re.findall(pattern, html_content)

if matches:
    print("Found line with 'Basic':", matches[0])
else:
    print("No line containing 'Basic' found.")
```

Comment: Why not parse with BeautifulSoup and check for every `td`  after the "Basic" for `.isnumeric()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = """\
   <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-left:0pt;padding-Right:0.75pt;padding-Top:0.75pt;padding-Bottom:0pt;width:38.46%;" valign="top">
    <p style="margin-bottom:0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-left:13.7pt;;text-indent:0pt;;color:#000000;font-size:9pt;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;">Basic earnings (loss) per share</p></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-left:0pt;padding-Right:0.75pt;padding-Top:0.75pt;padding-Bottom:0pt;width:1.08%;" valign="bottom">
    <p style="text-align:right;margin-bottom:0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-left:0pt;;text-indent:0pt;;color:#000000;font-size:9pt;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;"> </p></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-left:0pt;padding-Right:0.75pt;padding-Top:0.75pt;padding-Bottom:0pt;width:1%;white-space:nowrap;" valign="bottom">
    <p style="margin-bottom:0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-left:0pt;;text-indent:0pt;;color:#000000;font-size:9pt;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;"> </p></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-left:0pt;padding-Right:0.75pt;padding-Top:0.75pt;padding-Bottom:0pt;width:9.22%;white-space:nowrap;" valign="bottom">
    <p style="text-align:right;margin-bottom:0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-left:0pt;;text-indent:0pt;;color:#000000;font-size:9pt;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;">0.08</p></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-left:0pt;padding-Right:0.75pt;padding-Top:0.75pt;padding-Bottom:0pt;width:1%;white-space:nowrap;" valign="bottom">
    <p style="margin-bottom:0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-left:0pt;;text-indent:0pt;;color:#000000;font-size:9pt;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;"> </p></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-left:0pt;padding-Right:0.75pt;padding-Top:0.75pt;padding-Bottom:0pt;width:1.08%;" valign="bottom">
    <p style="text-align:right;margin-bottom:0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-left:0pt;;text-indent:0pt;;color:#000000;font-size:9pt;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;"> </p></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-left:0pt;padding-Right:0.75pt;padding-Top:0.75pt;padding-Bottom:0pt;width:1%;white-space:nowrap;" valign="bottom">
    <p style="margin-bottom:0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-left:0pt;;text-indent:0pt;;color:#000000;font-size:9pt;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;"> </p></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-left:0pt;padding-Right:0.75pt;padding-Top:0.75pt;padding-Bottom:0pt;width:9.22%;white-space:nowrap;" valign="bottom">
    <p style="text-align:right;margin-bottom:0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-left:0pt;;text-indent:0pt;;color:#000000;font-size:9pt;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;">0.65</p></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-left:0pt;padding-Right:0.75pt;padding-Top:0.75pt;padding-Bottom:0pt;width:1%;white-space:nowrap;" valign="bottom">
    <p style="margin-bottom:0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-left:0pt;;text-indent:0pt;;color:#000000;font-size:9pt;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;"> </p></td>
"""


def isnumber(x):
    try:
        float(x)
        return True
    except:
        return False


soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")

# find the <td> that's having "Basic" word in it:
td_with_basic = soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == "td" and "Basic" in tag.text)

# find the next <td> that's numeric
num = td_with_basic.find_next(lambda tag: tag.name == "td" and isnumber(tag.text))

print(num.text.strip())
```

Prints:

```
0.08
```